# Listify en Wordpress no siempre guarda cordenadas, Alguna idea?

Tags: wordpress, webservice, api

Tengo un sitio en wordpress, que usa un plugin llamado Listify el cual funciona como un directorio que permite agregar los elementos que guardemos a un mapa minando servicios de Google para el Geocoding. Mi problema esta en que en ocasiones si guarda las coordenadas y en ocasiones no.

Tengo entendido que Listify usa WPJobs para separar la direccion(delimitada por comas) y hacer una consulta a la api de Maps la cual regresa las coordenadas.

Alguien ha tenido este problema o uno similar?
Como lo solucionarian?

Comment: Bienvenido te invito a dar un [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento de la pagina

Comment: Si la he usado antes, Raul y aunque no es una duda en concreto queria saber si alguien lo ha pasado

Comment: Yo nunca lo he usado pero, esos punto si tendran coordenadas?

Comment: Si, pues como comentaba si funciona, solo a veces tengo que darle en actualizar muchas veces para que genere las coordenadas